# Convert Alpha version apk to Production apk in play store

Tags: google-play-services

I am new for android. Recently upload an apk as alpha version on play store. now complete all testing in alpha .Now i want final alpha version as a production apk. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sign your app with a release key, check the [Manually sign an APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#release-mode) for instruction. Anyway's the step-by-step instruction to finally publish it in Google play is found in [Launch checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist.html).